# What type of light is this?

Tags: lighting

I have inherited 4 of these outside lights which appear to be very solid and well made but i'm not sure how to make best use of them.

[image: Side view]

[image: Front view]

Comment: Step one - find an LED replacement for the bulb....

Comment: It doesn't fit in the hole in the deck behind the light?

Comment: Looks like a swimming pool niche fixture. What is its voltage?

Comment: They're flush-mount halogen lights. You can see the keyed ring on the face. They'll get very hot and use much more energy than modern LED lights.

Answer (score 2):

Those are similar to a open wiring lamp I have installed in offices but in a waterproof fixture . They are most likely mr16 12v 20w lamps (the coated reflector gives them away) they could be a higher voltage but not likely to be above the NEC touch limit for wet locations.

Comment: In one of the last offices I worked in, changing these bulbs was almost someone's full time job. They're the kind no one who pays for their own bulbs, likes. But if you're a design firm in the early 2000s, go nuts I guess.

Comment: @mazura, if the type of light I was thinking they have a very short life span. And yes the ones were on fancy lighting fixtures where they were going for a look not economical as the lamps are expensive and short life span.

Answer (score 0):

Drill a clearnce hole for the threads and use the brass? Colored nut to hold the lamp in place.

Look like a halogen bulb inside.

Perhaps can be used as deck lights or outside downlights.